# How to set date format depending on incoming other attribute value in Yii2 model

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-model, yii2-validation

I want to save Task model, but cannot do it without define date.
I have boolean attribute `allDay` (checkbox in view) and if it set in TRUE date format should be `d-m-Y`; else 'd-m-Y H:m'.
How to define this condition in `rules()` method?

Next code not work:

```php
public function rules() {
    return [
        [['title', 'user_id'], 'required'],
        [['description'], 'string'],
        [['start', 'end'], 'date', 
            'format' => $this->allDay ? 'php:d-m-Y' : 'php:d-m-Y H:i'],
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [inline validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#inline-validators) for this or set [condition](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-validation.html#conditional-validation) in rules. For condition do this:

```
[['start', 'end'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:d-m-Y', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return $model->allDay;
}],
[['start', 'end'], 'date', 'format' => 'php:d-m-Y H:i', 'when' => function ($model) {
    return !$model->allDay;
}],
```